# What was the item that Lucius Malfoy refused to sell to Borgin?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, deleted-scenes

In a deleted scene for "*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*" film, Harry (hidden in the Vanishing Cabinet?) observes Draco Malfoy and Lucius Malfoy going to Borgin and Burke's shop, and Malfoy informing Borgin that he is there to sell, not to buy items, due to raids by the Ministry. So far, close to the book.

Then, in a scene where the book has Malfoy giving Borgin a parchment with a list of items he wishes to sell, the movie's deleted scene instead has him put down a big box full of items, and Borgin examines them one by one.

In the middle, Borgin picks up an item, and Lucius forcefully tells him "This particular item... is **NOT** for sale!". Borgin then replies "I... I understand... It has *unique* qualities. One wouldn't want to see it fall into the wrong hands".

However, the scene is quite dark and murky and focus is on their faces. So it's entirely unclear which item Lucius refused to sell.

**Is there any *canon* info on what that item was?** (including movie canon).

My best guess would be that it was implied to have been Tom Riddle's Diary, but I am at a loss to find any evidence confirming that.

Comment: I don't think there's any canon info, especially since it was a deleted scene. A bunch of wiki entries say it's the diary, but there's no official confirmation.

Comment: In this case canon includes things like production notes, scripts, cast/crew interviews etc...

Comment: I know, that's what I meant.

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately my copy of the script omits this scene, and I can’t find any interviews that discuss it.

Comment: @alexwlchan - The wikia says it was the diary, but with no referencing.

Comment: @Richard - that's because someone writing the wikia isn't wise enough to honestly say "I don't know, I'm just guessing out of my behind". Par for the course for Wikia

Comment: i do not think it is the diary, when the shop keeper is handling it, its making a tinkering sound, like a metal. so definitely its not the diary. if it is anything, i think its the necklace draco tries to use to kill dumbledore in the half-blood prince. maybe malfoy gave it to Borgin for safekeeping as he cannot keep it in his house because of the raids. and later when draco needed it he went there and got it from him. just an assumption. i don't know how borgin is touching it without being cursed by it. maybe it has some triggering point... it's killing me to not surely know about the object.

Comment: Doesn't seem likely that it would be the diary—there's no way, after all, that Borgin could know that the diary had any “_unique_ qualities”. Horcruxes don't really advertise their Horcruxiness.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, the phrase 'unique qualities' doe not (and should not) mean Borgin knew what the diary really was. Didn't even Dumbledore figure it out much later than the second book?

Comment: @skip405 What else is there about the diary that's unique? Especially something you can tell just by looking at it. It's implied that Dumbledore figured it out at the end of the book, but then he didn't know about the diary before that. My point was that since Borgin **couldn't** possibly have recognised the diary on sight as anything other than a diary, and since he **does** recognise whatever Lucius is holding and knows that it has unique qualities, the thing Lucius is holding is not likely to be the diary.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, imagine you are such a seller, you've seen tons of dark stuff, you used to be Tom's employer. If you just saw the name of the owner, you definitely have all the reasons to say that object had unique qualities, simply because you know what that kid was capable of, no? Also, a non-verbal spell on it may 'tell' you something, or a quick flick through will reveal the pages are blank (no-brainer to figure out it either has hidden text or can 'answer' to the writer). Yes, I know it isn't shown that he manages to examine the object _properly_...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, you are more than welcome to dwell upon [my answer to this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/74052/36823) and figure out where that object ended up, if it's not the diary. It was no 'poison'-level, right? Something much darker and 'embarrassing', Malfoy couldn't have brought it back home, could he?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may well have been the **advanced Time-Turner** seen in [Harry Potter and the Cursed Child](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29056083-harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child). It certainly possesses the quality of "*uniqueness*" that Malfoy Sr. prizes so strongly.

> **DRACO:** *The Time-Turner the Ministry seized was a prototype. Made of inexpensive metal. It does the job — sure. But only being able to
>   go back in time for five minutes — that’s a serious flaw — it isn’t
>   something you’d sell to true collectors of Dark Magic.*
>
> HARRY realizes what DRACO is saying.
>
> **HARRY:** *He was working for you?*
>
> **DRACO:** *No. **My father. He liked owning things that no one else had.** The Ministry’s Time-Turners — thanks to Croaker — were always a
>   little vanilla for him. He wanted the ability to go back further than
>   an hour, he wanted the ability to travel back years. He’d never have
>   used it. Secretly I think he preferred a world without Voldemort.
>   **But yes, the Time-Turner was built for him.***

Comment: I don't like comparing film to book and trying to find any sort of logic there, especially a deleted scene. It seems unlikely that in either case (parchment list from the book, or the box from the film[ish] - that his special time turner would be in any sort of position to be seen or sold to a shopkeeper. I'll still vote for you though because I can't prove it wasn't either :)

Comment: @NKCampbell - This is comparing film to play. Neither from Rowling. Still clever answer. +1

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - It's not really a spoiler (per se). Almost the entire play is about time-turners. Basically that's the only way they could shoe-horn all the old characters from the first 7 books into the new play.

Comment: @Valorum - if they add time-traveling robots, I might actually bother reading, then.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Plenty of time-traveling, alas no robots.

Comment: @Valorum - so... basically JKR... or whoever wrote this... stole the whole thing from HISHE? :)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - That was [precisely my thought](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsYWT5Q_R_w&feature=youtu.be&t=2m51s) as I was reading it.

Comment: Am I the only one here who thinks the phrases 'unique qualities' and 'quality of uniqueness' are far from meaning the same thing? Have to admit, I'm not a native English speaker, may be mistaken.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if you find it canon enough, but I'll try to explain why I think it was the diary with a simple fact. **Borgin took the whole chest, not the items themselves.** Let me recreate two scenes then.

Let's first imagine it's *not* Tom Riddle's diary, but something else entirely.
*The diary was not in the chest then, but in Malfoy's pocket.* So Malfoy left the shop carrying **two** dark items to give to two different people, one he would eventually give to Ginny and that other one from the chest to... someone else (not seen in the book or movie). It is a bit more complicated for Malfoy if it's not the diary. I guess slipping dark items into other people's cauldrons is not the thing you wish to do more than once in one day )) Although he could have taken the item back home, but why put it in the chest in the first place, just not to sell it?

Now let's imagine that it *is* the diary. He carried all the dark stuff in one chest, sold all but one item, disposed of that other one whilst still in Diagon Alley, came back home item-less )

You cannot find the confirmation of the first scene anywhere, but you *can* find the confirmation of the second one. Because it's **shown** that way.

Answer (score -3):

I believe it was the diary. He had in mind who he wished to drop said item off. In a scene or two later. When he puts it in the cauldron of Ginny Weasley... too bad the movie never showed the fight scene betwixt Draco's father and Mr. Weasley like the book stated...

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Do you have any evidence to support your claim?  Although a valid theory, we really need some evidence to support the theory!

Answer (score -3):

I just watched the scene and it appears that the item he takes out of the box is too small to be the diary. Possibly the ring with the resurrection stone?

Comment: The ring with the Resurrection Stone was lying concealed under the floorboards in the Gaunt shack at this time, so definitely not that.

Answer (score -6):

borgin wanted to buy one of the twin cabinets which were like a transportation equipment

Comment: Why do you think this is the case?

Comment: 100% false. The cabinets are taller than a human. The item was a small item held inside a small head-sized box